# More or less - Widespread idiom?

Tags: italian

I've encountered *more or less* in many different languages. Why is this idiom so widespread? In a few other languages such as Italian it's "more or less", but in Albanian it's "less or more".

Comment: Well, it's (a) a useful marker of degree of accuracy, which comes up in any culture; and (b) something that can be cobbled together easily from leftover pieces of grmmatical plumbing, namely two contrasting chunks of a comparative construction -- something every language has lying around -- held together with duck tape of logical disjunction (`OR`). It doesn't have any object, and it gets accompanied by a handwave in most languages. The handwave is probly the thing to study, not the expression -- the expression is just a tinkertoy.

Comment: I see what you mean, basically it's an expression of two extremes, being on the 'safe side' you would be inclusive rather than exclusive. I hadn't thought about the handwave motion...

Comment: Like _bye-bye, yea big,_ and _c'mon,_ the hand gesture is an emblem of the speech event, and can substitute for it in silence, if the context is understood. David McNeill is the one to read about gestures and language.

Comment: It's probably a result of calquing, a.k.a. loan translation: that is, a phrase that's borrowed from one language into another by word-for-word translation. This is a very common phenomenon. (For another example, compare *I have no idea, Je n'ai aucune idée, No tengo ni idea*.) Presumably "more or less" originated in one European language and then spread into others.

Comment: Can anyone add some tags to this questions? I'd suggest "Idioms", "Claque"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, I was making a list of languages that use the 'less-or-more' form, after first noticing it in Paul-Wexler's lecture, before his lecture, I assumed "less or more" is the more common form, as I'm fluent in Hebrew (where it's "less or more") and English (where's it's "more or less"), but I also spoke (not fluently) at the time two other languages where it happens to be "less or more" (Polish and Dutch), only after hearing Wexler - I've checked and seen "more or less" - is "more common".
Wexler claimed the "less or more" version is a "Persian calque" and mentioned Sorbian and Polish do it too, maybe it's true through older records. Since then - I've found that -

1. Serbo-Croatian - accepts *both* (manje-više / više-manje) ; (where as in other languages inverting the order sounds very awkward...)
2. Albanian, Turkish, Persian, Hebrew, Polish,  Sorbian, Lithuanian, Dutch, Frisian, Afrikaans, Basque  - say "less or more" (correct me if I'm wrong about any of these)
3. All sounds "kindof chinese" in a way. (Mandarin way to phrasing adjectives), Wexler in his lecture - mentioned a lot of Silk-Road related borrowing for such expressions, since they *are* used a lot in trade.